# child form overflows mat-form-field width

Tags: angular, angular-material

I created an angular component that handles North American Phone Numbers.  It works exactly as it should.  Unfortunately, when I enclose it in a parent mat-form-field, the child extends beyond the width of the parent.  I would like to get the parent to track the width of the child since not all fields have to be visible, depending on application usage. (e.g., the phone type select, the toll '+1' and checkbox and/or the 'x' + extension input field.)

I can programatically set the width of the mat-form-field in the app or with css, but I can't get the correct value from the component to automate it.

[Test showing mat-form-field with aqua background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbpih.png)

TypeScript:

```
 import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { UsPhoneNumber } from './_classes/us-phone-number';
import { UsPhoneNumberComponent } from './_components/us-phone-number/us-phone-number.component';
import { FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
 } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Phone Test';
  myform : FormGroup;
  zerror = true;
  matPhoneNumber : UsPhoneNumber;

  types: string[] = ['Home','Work','Cell']

  ddd: string = '8005551212';
  eee: string = '40773377721000'
  abc='auto';
  constructor(    
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder // private fm: FocusMonitor,
) {
  this.myform = formBuilder.group(
    {
      myPhone : new FormControl(new UsPhoneNumber('4777337777')),
      matPhone : new FormControl(new UsPhoneNumber('18005551212'))
    })
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]='myform'>
    <app-us-phone-number formControlName='myPhone' [phoneTypes]='types' #ppp [value]="ddd" (phoneEvent)="onChange($event)"></app-us-phone-number>
    <br/>
    <mat-form-field appearance='outline' [ngStyle]="{'width':abc}">
        <mat-label>Phone Number</mat-label>
        <mat-hint>Area Code optional</mat-hint>
        <app-us-phone-number formControlName='matPhone' [phoneTypes]='types' #mmm [value]="eee" (phoneEvent)="onMatChange($event)"></app-us-phone-number>
        <mat-error *ngIf="mmm.errorState">{{matPhoneNumber.errmsg}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: You are saying you want to get the width of app-us-phone-number? I do not understand why you need to assign the width value.

Comment: All I want is to have the mat-form-field automatically sized correctly so its contents don't overflow the width.  How that is done is not important (unless its 100's of lines of code;) ).  I have tried very many options with no success.

Comment: did you set a width value of 'app-us-phone-number'?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be what you want. Put this in your styles.css.

```
.mat-form-field-infix {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

Live Example: https://angular-material-form-field-wrapping-content.stackblitz.io

Comment: Thanks, but no success.  The only thing that seems to work is:

Comment: mat-form-field
{
  width: 308px; // <<< the value calculated by the child

Comment: }

mat-form-field-infix doesn't change anything, even when set to 308px

One of these days I'll remember to hit the Shift key when pressing enter on these inputs :(

Comment: Setting the width of <app-us-phone-number> changes the width of the child, but does not change the width of the parent.

I just tried replacing the <app-us-phone-number> with <input matInput> with varying widths of the input field and mat-form-field width does not change.

I have a hack that will work temporarily (adding a width field to the UsPhoneNumber class) but I think this may be a bug in mat-form-field so I will submit a bug report when I get the rest of my app working (several weeks, but I am on a deadline),

Thanks again.

Comment: Okay, so the example I made is not what you want?

Comment: WOW ... this tiny piece of CSS fixed my issue with mat-form-fields overflowing their parent container.  thanks so much @wannadream :)